# Update & Upgrade Docker distribution on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, boot2docker

At the moment I've got Docker v.1.7 and I'd want to upgrade it to latest (1.8 at the moment).

**Important part:** I want to do this without installing Docker and boot2docker again. I wasn't able to find any info about it.

Is it possible? And how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have boot2docker, the upgrade is the usual:

```
boot2docker stop
boot2docker download
boot2docker start

docker@boot2docker:~$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.8.1
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   d12ea79
 Built:        Thu Aug 13 02:49:29 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

That being said, going forward, **[docker machine](https://github.com/docker/machine)** is the recommended project to use.
See "[Get started with Docker Machine and a local VM](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/)".

Comment: I've tried it, it didn't worked. My client is still in v.1.7

Comment: @michasm what did `boot2docker download` returned? It works without issue for me. Make sure the boot2docker-vm is completely hsutdown in VirtualBox first.

Comment: It returned me latest 1.8.x version. Still running vm in VirtualBox might be the case. I'll check it later.

Comment: that could be it, after manually shutdown machine in VirtualBox it worked. I dont' know why it didn't shutdown by it's own.

Answer (score 13):

This is an old thread, but I just had the same issue on Windows and the accepted answer didn't work for me, so I'm posting this for others who come along.

You can check your version by opening your Docker Quick Start terminal and running:

`$ docker --version
 Docker version 17.10.0-ce, build f4ffd25`

To update all you had to do is run `$ docker-machine upgrade`

```
User1234@HP-1234 MINGW64 ~
$ docker-machine upgrade
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Upgrading docker...
Stopping machine to do the upgrade...
Upgrading machine "default"...
Default Boot2Docker ISO is out-of-date, downloading the latest release...
Latest release for github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker is v18.01.0-ce
Downloading C:\Users\User1234\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso from https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v18.01.0-ce/boot2docker.iso...
0%....10%....20%....30%....40%....50%....60%....70%....80%....90%....100%
Copying C:\Users\User1234\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\User1234\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso...
Starting machine back up...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a dhcp server. Sometimes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
(default) Waiting for an IP...
Restarting docker...
```

Comment: indeed, this is quite old question. From the time I've asked it the `boot2docker` has become obsolete and we all migrated to `docker-machine` which you're using. Thus - good to keep your answer, if somebody find it now it would be useful :)

Comment: I found it very useful just now. Thank you!