# upgrade docker engine on windows

Tags: docker, docker-machine

surprising there is no doc out there ([Update & Upgrade Docker distribution on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151372/update-upgrade-docker-distribution-on-windows) - not even working for me) to upgrade the docker engine on windows.

I have tried the following but keep on failing:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also tried from the UI, when i clicked 'install update' but nothing happened and the UI disapeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since docker desktop is maintained by hyper-v you cannot upgrade using cli or the docker UI, so what i did re-installing the Docker Desktop Installer and it managed to upgrade.

Comment: Thats right - I just had to re download and install from [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm. There no longer appears to be a way to run the upgrade from the CLI. `Docker machine` has been removed from Docker Desktop and also the `Docker-toolbox` is deprecated by now.

So the only way to update Docker Desktop on Windows, is to [download](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/) and run the installer.

The installer will ask you, whether you want to upgrade. Just hit `confirm` and it'll upgrade it for you.